# Powershell v5 Get-ChildItem -File not working?

Tags: powershell, loops, iteration, ps

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Recurse -File | ForEach-Object `
{
    Write-Host $_.fullname
}
```

```
Get-ChildItem : A parameter cannot be found that matches
parameter name 'File'.
```

```
Version
-------
5.1.17763.771
```

I have many other ps scripts running that use this and it works fine, but for some reason it's not working in this new script I wrote. What's going on?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  I'm unable to reproduce your issue.  What do you see if you type `Get-Command Get-ChildItem`?

Comment: `CommandType     Name
-----------     ----
Cmdlet          Get-ChildItem`

Comment: Type `Get-Command Get-PowerShell | Format-List` to see some detail around the ParameterSets and the source DLL.  I'm just wondering if something redefined the CmdLet on you.

Comment: Get-Powershell is not recognized

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant `Get-Command Get-ChildItem | Format-List`

Comment: [-File] is clearly listed there.

Comment: Can you add some more code, or provide a complete minimal script that demonstrates the error?  My guess is that PowerShell is selecting a different parameter set, but without seeing more of the surrounding code, it's hard to tell.

Comment: Is there mode code to go along with that ForEach-Object command?

Comment: Please check edited OP for full code.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you everyone for helping.

The value of $dir was

```
" S:\folder\folder\"
```

Removing the space before the drive letter resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the OP's particular instance, there are other cases where this error can occur.  `Get-ChildItem` can be used on other providers besides the file provider (e.g., the registry), and the `-File` switch is not valid in those cases.

Example:

```bsh
$dir = 'C:\Temp'
Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -File     # Works just fine

$dir = 'HKCU:\Software'
Get-ChildItem -Path $dir           # Works without -File switch
Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -File     # Throws "parameter cannot be found" error
```

Answer (score 0):

That wasn't the source of the problem for me.
All I did was surround the variable with ( ) and that resolve it.
In my case I wanted the full filename of the 'found' file

```
$curdir = "C:\Program Files\"
(Get-Childitem -Path ($curdir) -File -filter "node.exe" -recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Directory.FullName
```

In your case I'm sure just using this would work for you:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path ($dir) -Recurse -File | ForEach-Object `
{
    Write-Host $_.fullname
}
```